# Launch Count on iPhone App

Tags: iphone, launch, leaderboard

Ok I want to keep track of how many times my iPhone App has been launched. I will be using this number for a "leader board" for our most active user. I figured the code needs to be in the -DidBecomeActive method being that in iOS4 the app may remain in the background for sometime.

Now I know it's probably trivial and i'm just making it more difficult than necessary but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this! Just want the launch number to increase by 1 every time the app is launched or returned from the background.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [**NSUserDefaults**](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger launchCount = [prefs integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
launchCount++;
NSLog(@"Application has been launched %d times", launchCount);
[prefs setInteger:launchCount  forKey:@"launchCount"];
```